# Change string to number in javascript

Tags: javascript, type-conversion

Hello to everyone i need to get the sum of the numbers but i got only string, so i need get numbers. How i should change it to number? i have tried parseInt and Number but nothing helps

```js
var td = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
var input = document.getElementById("myInput");


for ( var i = 0; i < td.length; i++ ){
  td[i].addEventListener("click", activeTd);
 }



function activeTd(event){
 var result = 0;
 for ( var i = 0; i < td.length; i++ ){
  event.target.style.color = "red";
  
 }
    var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
 btn.addEventListener("click", activeAll);

 function activeAll(){
  if( event.target.style.color = "red" ){
   result = Number(event.target.innerHTML);
   input.value += result;
  }
    }
 
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>54</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>22</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="text" id="myInput">
<button id="myBtn">Start</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `value` of an `input` element is always a string - so when you add that string to another variable, even if that other variable is a `number`, cocatenation is what results, instead of addition. Cast the `input.value` to a number first:

```js
var td = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
var input = document.getElementById("myInput");


for (var i = 0; i < td.length; i++) {
  td[i].addEventListener("click", activeTd);
}



function activeTd(event) {
  var result = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < td.length; i++) {
    event.target.style.color = "red";

  }
  var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
  btn.addEventListener("click", activeAll);

  function activeAll() {
    if (event.target.style.color = "red") {
      input.value = Number(event.target.textContent) + Number(input.value);
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>54</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>22</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="text" id="myInput" value="0">
<button id="myBtn">Start</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your target `input.value` is a string any addition returns a string, even if a value is a number. You need to take then value of `input.value`, convert it to number, add the value as number and assign it back.

```
input.value = +input.value + +event.target.innerHTML
```

```js
var td = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
var input = document.getElementById("myInput");

for (var i = 0; i < td.length; i++) {
    td[i].addEventListener("click", activeTd);
}

function activeTd(event) {
    var result = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < td.length; i++) {
        event.target.style.color = "red";
    }
    var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
    btn.addEventListener("click", activeAll);

    function activeAll() {
        if (event.target.style.color = "red") {
            input.value = +input.value + +event.target.innerHTML
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<table><tr><td>1</td><td>11</td><td>8</td></tr><tr><td>54</td><td>13</td><td>22</td></tr><tr><td>15</td><td>23</td><td>6</td></tr></table>
<input type="text" id="myInput">
<button id="myBtn">Start</button>
```

Comment: just a hint, you could prevent the input of strings (which give `NaN`, not a number) on input by using the `disabled` attribute.